# GWT RequestFactory not persisting attached entities

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I'm trying to get the hang of the new [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) API and having a really tough time of it.

My domain models consist of a `Staffer`, a `Person` and an `Office`.  Staffer has a Person and an Office as fields.

When I try to save updates to a Staffer instance in GWT, on the server-side `persist()` call I see the updates in its primitive/String fields, but I do not see updates to the attached `Person` or `Office` objects. Here is how I'm affecting the edits on the GWT side:

```
private void persistStafferDetails()
{
    CRMRequestFactory.StafferRequest stafferRequest = requestFactory.stafferRequest();
    staffer = stafferRequest.edit(staffer);

    PersonProxy person = staffer.getPerson();
    person.setFirstName(firstNameField.getText());
    person.setLastName(lastNameField.getText());

    staffer.setPersonalEmail(personalEmailField.getText());
    staffer.getHomeLocation().setStreetAddress(addressField1.getText());
    staffer.getHomeLocation().setCity(cityField.getText());
    staffer.getHomeLocation().setPostalCode(postalField.getText());
    staffer.getHomeLocation().setProvince(provinceDropDown.getValue(provinceDropDown.getSelectedIndex()));

    stafferRequest.persist().using(staffer).fire();
}
```

Here are the proxies:

```
@ProxyFor(Staffer.class)
public interface StafferProxy extends EntityProxy
{
    Long getId();

    PersonProxy getPerson();
    void setPerson(PersonProxy person);

    OfficeProxy getOffice();
    void setOffice(OfficeProxy office);

    String getHomePhone();
    void setHomePhone(String homePhone);

    String getCellPhone();
    void setCellPhone(String cellPhone);

    String getPersonalEmail();
    void setPersonalEmail(String personalEmail);

    LocationProxy getHomeLocation();
    void setHomeLocation(LocationProxy homeLocation);
}

@ProxyFor(Person.class)
public interface PersonProxy extends EntityProxy
{
    Long getId();
    void setId(Long id);

    String getFirstName();
    void setFirstName(String firstName);

    String getLastName();
    void setLastName(String lastName);
}


@ProxyFor(Office.class)
public interface OfficeProxy extends EntityProxy
{
    Long getId();

    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}
```

And my CRMRequestFactory looks like:

```
public interface CRMRequestFactory extends RequestFactory
{
  @Service(Staffer.class)
    public interface StafferRequest extends RequestContext
    {
        InstanceRequest<StafferProxy, Void> persist();
        Request<List<StafferProxy>> getAll();
        Request<StafferProxy> findStaffer(Long id);
    }
    public StafferRequest stafferRequest();

    @Service(Person.class)
    public interface PersonRequest extends RequestContext
    {
        InstanceRequest<PersonProxy, Void> persist();
        Request<List<PersonProxy>> getAll();
        Request<PersonProxy> findPerson(Long id);
    }
    public PersonRequest personRequest();

    @Service(Office.class)
    public interface OfficeRequest extends RequestContext
    {
        InstanceRequest<OfficeProxy, Void> persist();
        Request<List<OfficeProxy>> getAll();
        Request<OfficeProxy> findOffice(Long id);
    }
    public OfficeRequest officeRequest();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RequestFactory doesn't treat the `persist()` method as anything special, so you have to implement chained persists on your own or configure your ORM system to do it for you.  Another thing to check is that the `findPerson()` and `findOffice()` methods return the same object instance of the Person or Office object if called more than once.  If you use the same `EntityManager` (or your system's equivalent) throughout the lifetime of the incoming HTTP request, that usually takes care of the "missing updates" problem with non-trivial payload graphs.

A [blog post](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-211-requestfactory-part-ii) about chained persistence and an issue [tracker link](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5389) with a short discussion.

If this doesn't help, could you post an example of your domain objects' `findFoo()` and `persist()` methods?

Comment: @BobV- what I meant was that when my persist() was called, the object passed in from the GWT side had updates to its primitive fields, but not to the fields of the embedded Person or Office objects. In other words, my persistence layer was never even getting a chance to see the updated fields. I'll check to see if the EntityManager-per-request could be the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, using the same EntityManager solved the problem.  Thanks!