# Gwt Client Validation with editor and request factory

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, gwt-editors, gwt-validation

I had a problems with GWT Client Validation used with RequestFactory and Editors.

The edit code is :

```
LocalityRequest localityContext = //create Request 
Locality locality = //Locality Entity Proxy loaded from the server
driver.edit(locality, localityContext); //Edit the proxy
request = localityContext.updateLocality(locality);
```

And the save code is :

```
this.localityContext = (LocalityRequest) driver.flush(); //Flush the request
Set<ConstraintViolation<LocalityProxy>> violations = validator.validate(this.locality); //Local validate the object
if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> sets = new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>(violations);
    driver.setConstraintViolations(sets);
    editLocalityView.setErrors(sets); //give errors to the editors
    return;
}
localityContext.fire(); //else send the request
```

My problems is that the local validation always validate on the loaded version and not the edited by user version.
How can we get the flushed object saved in the request ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cache/store the edited object (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789870/requestfactoryeditordriver-getting-edited-data-after-flush) for more details):

```
LocalityRequest localityContext = //create Request 
Locality locality = //Immutable Locality Entity Proxy loaded from the server
Locality modifedLocality = ctx.edit(locality); // Create Mutable copy 
driver.edit(modifedLocality, localityContext); //Edit the mutable proxy
request = localityContext.updateLocality(modifedLocality);
```

And in the save code:

```
this.localityContext = (LocalityRequest) driver.flush(); //Flush the request
Set<ConstraintViolation<LocalityProxy>> violations = validator.validate(this.modifedLocality); //Local validate the mutable Proxy
if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> sets = new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>(violations);
    driver.setConstraintViolations(sets);
    editLocalityView.setErrors(sets); //give errors to the editors
    return;
}
localityContext.fire(); //else send the request
```

Comment: Thanks, normaly the ctx.edit() is doing by the driver.edit. If we pass a mutable proxy to the driver, the driver will not call the edit method ?

Comment: AFAIK the edit call by the driver is a nop when you pass a mutable proxy